# grep not returning expected result in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to get back a list of field names from a data.frame in R that have "mean()" within them.

However, as an example, if I run:

```
grep("mean()", "fld_meanFreq()")
```

It returns an answer, i.e. 1, when I would expect 0.

When I do something similar on the list of field names, I'm getting field names containing both "mean()" and "meanFreq()".

How to fix please? I didn't see anything that dealt with this in a search on here.

Comment: You need to escape the parenthesis if you mean to match them literally. something like `grep("mean\\(\\)", "fld_meanFreq()")` should work.

Comment: `grep` is supposed to find *patterns* and it uses `regex`. See `?regex` to have an introduction to the matter. If you want *exact* match, you have to add the `fixed=TRUE` argument: `grep("mean()", "fld_meanFreq()",fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: That worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: both of those worked.  I screwed up and only put a single \ when I was trying to escape it before I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` assumes that the first argument is a regular expression, if you don't supply the `fixed=TRUE` option.  In your example, the parentheses in `mean()` stand for a subexpression (an empty one in this case), so your example is pretty equivalent to

```
grep("mean", "fld_meanFreq()")
```

Instead, try:

```
grep("mean()", "fld_meanFreq()", fixed=TRUE)
```

For more information about regular expressions, read the R help on `regex`.